# Get dates in 4 quarters in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get a report that gives me data in four quarters.

For example from:

```
1/1/2015-3/31/2015 as Q1
4/1/2015-6/30/2015 as Q2
7/1/2015-9/30/2015 as Q3 
10/1/2015- 12/31/2015 as Q4
```

the dates are in this format : 2015-01-01 00:00.000.

How can I get the output of dates in 4 quarters in SQL Server?

I tried:

```
select count (cctransactions), avg(visits) 
(CASE WHEN MONTH(1/1/2015) >= 1 AND MONTH(3/31/2015) <=3 THEN'Q1' 
WHEN MONTH(4/1/2015) >= 4 AND MONTH(6/30/2015) <=6 THEN'Q2' 
WHEN MONTH(7/1/2015) >= 7 AND MONTH(9/31/2015) <=9 THEN'Q3' 
WHEN MONTH(10/1/2015) >= 10 AND MONTH(12/31/2015) <=12 THEN 'Q4' END) AS   'QUARTER' 
FROM [Database].[dbo].[transactionMaster] 
Group by cctransactions, ‘Quarter’
```

but this gave me an error saying GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference. I am not sure how to do an outer select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want to achieve. But I'd suggest using MONTH and CASE statement. This will properly label data which quarter they belong to.

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN MONTH(FieldDate) >= 1 AND MONTH(FieldDate) <=3
        THEN
            'Q1'
        WHEN MONTH(FieldDate) >= 4 AND MONTH(FieldDate) <=6
        THEN
            'Q2'
        WHEN MONTH(FieldDate) >= 7 AND MONTH(FieldDate) <=9
        THEN
            'Q3'
        WHEN MONTH(FieldDate) >= 10 AND MONTH(FieldDate) <=12
        THEN
            'Q4'
    END 'QUARTER',
    Field1,
    Field2,
    ...
    FieldX 
FROM 
    [DataBase].[dbo].[SomeTable];
WHERE
    YEAR(FieldDate) = @YEAR
```

Comment: Use an outer select from the above query and Group By Quarter. Of course you need to select the cctransactions in the subquery.

Answer (score 4):

To work out which quarter a date is in use

```
DATEPART(QUARTER, @theDate)
```

If you want this formatted as Q1 etc then just prepend 'Q' :)

You can `GROUP BY` this if you want to aggregate your report by quarter.

Consider adding a Dates table to your application with pre-calculated quarters, first/last day of month, financial periods etc.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms174420.aspx

Comment: select count (cctransactions), avg(visits), 
DATEPART(QUARTER, QuoteIssueDate) as 'Quarter' 
FROM [Database].[dbo].[transactionMaster] 
group by 'Quater'                                                                                                  I get an error saying Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: In MariaDB you can use `EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM date_field)`